# Trouble populating input textbox after selecting dropdown option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to populate some input fields based on the options selected by the User via a dropdown menu.

HTML of the drop down menu:

```
 <label>Select a Template </label>
 <select name="mailTemplates" class="form-control">
 <option id="placeOrder" value="">Place Order</option>
 <option id="cancelOrder" value="">Cancel Order</option>
 <option id="reqInfo" value="">Request Information</option>
 <option value="" disabled selected>-- Select a Mail Template --</option>
 </select>


<label>Subject</label>
<input id="subject" class="form-control " type="text" name="subject" placeholder="Subject of your email"/>
```

JQuery for click function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#placeOrder").on('click', function(){
            $("#subject").val("Test Subject");
        });
});
```

When the user selects the "Place Order" option, it should populate the #subject [input box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nOg6U.jpg) with "Test Subject".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the `id` of the selected option along with `change()` like the following:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#mailTemplates").change(function(){
    var optionId = $("option:selected", this).attr('id');
    if(optionId == 'placeOrder'){
      $("#subject").val("Test Subject");
    }
    else
      $("#subject").val("");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Select a Template </label>
  <select name="mailTemplates" id="mailTemplates" class="form-control">
  <option id="placeOrder" value="">Place Order</option>
  <option id="cancelOrder" value="">Cancel Order</option>
  <option id="reqInfo" value="">Request Information</option>
  <option value="" disabled selected>-- Select a Mail Template --</option>
</select>


<label>Subject</label>
<input id="subject" class="form-control " type="text" name="subject" placeholder="Subject of your email"/>
```

Comment: And need to highlight that there is no need to set `id` on `option` with this answer. so remove all options/s id/

Comment: @Pedram, then how to trace that this is the specific option to check with?

Comment: @Mamun The right way is/ set value for options not id and get it by value. by the way it works fine by id/s but empty value? then id? so better remove id and fill up value.

Comment: @Pedram, I understood your point but I didn't want to change OP's content in greater context...thanks for point.